# How can I remove all but the last N elements from an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array. I have a variable that shows how many elements in the array must be left at the end. Is there a function that would do that? Example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var n = 2;
arr = someFunction(n); // arr = [4, 5];
```

I want an array with the last `n` elements in it.

Comment: [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?  `arr.slice(-2)` returns `[4,5]`.

Comment: `arr = arr.slice(~n+1);`

Comment: "*remove last part of array*" "*in the array must be left at the end*". Those are complete opposites - do you want to keep or remove the end? Are you trying to extract the end or remove it?

Comment: @h2ooooooo See my edit, it should be clear.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: How did you know if we wanted the original array modified or not?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's clear to me from seeing `arr = [4, 5];`

Comment: @RocketHazmat What would cause your doubt?

Comment: @adeneo: Why, just why

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I just re-read the question, and "how many elements in the array must be left at the end", now it makes sense. :-)

Comment: @minitech - bitwise operators are just so lovely I try to use them everywhere ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The slice method is what you want.  It returns a new object, so you must replace your existing object with the new one.

```
arr = arr.slice(-1 * n);
```

Alternatively, modify the existing array with `splice()`.

```
arr.splice(0, arr.length - n);
```

Splice is the more efficient, since it is not copying elements.

Comment: Instead of `-1 * n`, you can just do `-n`.

Comment: Sure.  Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Just to clarify if this doesn't make sense to someone: `splice` will return the first set of elements, but it will also **remove** them from the actual array. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice